# Lightning Components: what is the easiest way to get the components DOM root element without a wrapper in the markup?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, dom

I'm having a couple of very different components and often I need to do some work on the components root DOM-node. Some of the compos have Version<=39.0 other have 40.0+ and therefore I'm not looking for anything which is relaying on Locker Service Secure Window.

I know already it works fine like this

```
<div aura:id="thisIsTheRoot">...</div>
```

and

```
var rootElement = component.find("thisIsTheRoot").getElement();
```

But I don't like the wrapper. Can't we do it easier without wrapper and just pure Javascript? Isn't there a framework-function for this already in place? Wouldn't it be nice to have something like

```
component.getDOMRootElement();
```

?

This would help me, because I'm writing JS residing in a static resource which should work across all of my components regardless of any markup-wrapper.

Comment: Maybe try getGlobalId()?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no way to get at the root element directly. The closest you could probably get to would be to get `component.get('v.body')`, which will return all of the components in the component.

Comment: @sfdcfox actually JRiffe's comment lead me to this jquery construct which provides a kind of root element `$('[data-aura-rendered-by="'+cmp.getGlobalId()+'"]').get(0)` (sorry I'm to bad to write it in vanilla JS but it means "give me the element which has data-aura-redered-by equal to getGlobalId()"). **For v<=39 it works great!!** Not tested for v40+ and maybe the Locker Service is cutting access just one single level below... :-(

Comment: @UweHeim the vanilla version would just be `document.querySelector('[data-aura-rendered-by="'+ cmp.getGlobalId()+'"]')`. I would expect Locker Service to not be okay with this request because of the Shadow DOM that it uses.

Comment: @sfdcfox too bad of Locker Service, but probably you are right. One DOM-Level below that we can grab only the loose guts of the inner markup. The Locker Service should grant us this single one extra level scope since it is for sure no harm or security nightmare of having a root of our own compo, which Salesforce is wrapping around it automatically. In my opinion it's the opposite: it would be very useful.

Comment: @UweHeim I agree there should be the ability to get the component's source, since it is already wrapped up for you.

Comment: You can use `component.getElement()` which returns the root element of your component.

Comment: @Praveen component.getElement() returns null for me.